# Displaying base64 pdf data in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, base64

I'm making a web app with a webmail.
I want to display mail attachments (like pdf, jpg, gif) in iframe but have some problem with it.

In iFrame I cannot send extra header - I need them for authorization - so I can't use iframe's `src` for simple url.

I have to make ajax request with custom headers and send file as `base64` data.
As for image it works but have big problem with `PDF`

- `$("#output_iframe_id").attr('src', "data:application/pdf;base64," + response);` that code always has crashed pdf.
- `$("#output_iframe_id").contents().find('html').html(response);` that one is displaying raw data

How to do it?

Comment: You can use External library to view pdfs like pdf.js https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/